# How to automate the API call of a button in a website?

Tags: web-scraping, postman

I am in a web app where I need to click a button every 2m and 30s. Out of curiosity, I wanted to see if I could automate this action.

So I started by trying to make the call the action of the button makes, in postman. Here's the URL of the button:

https://s43-gr.ikariam.gameforge.com/?action=PiracyScreen&function=capture&buildingLevel=1&view=pirateFortress&cityId=11055&position=17&activeTab=tabBootyQuest&backgroundView=city&currentCityId=11055&templateView=pirateFortress&actionRequest=0de6d9e98b3423da9d6c6db1a832ef54

I tried making a GET request and although I get a status of 200, nothing seems to happen.
I don’t really know how to do this, I just tried with my basic knowledge.

Comment: Why are you using Postman to click buttons on a UI?

Comment: No, I'm using it to make the call the button makes

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: That my call would simulate the action of pressing the button

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't?

Comment: Because the action on the website is still available